# How is Gzip Compression Enabled in Express.js Despite Absence of Explicit Configuration?

Tags: node.js, express, compression, gzip, middleware

I have a Node.js/Express.js web application running on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu server. I haven't explicitly configured Gzip compression in my codebase, yet I noticed that my server seems to be sending responses encoded with Gzip. Here's a list of the packages I'm using:

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt-nodejs");
const cors = require("cors");
const knex = require('knex');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config()
const _ = require('lodash');
```

I've read about the `compression` npm package that enables Gzip encoding, but I haven't explicitly included it in my dependencies. Could someone please help me understand how Gzip compression might be enabled in my Express.js application without explicit configuration? Does DigitalOcean's Ubuntu server have default settings that automatically enable Gzip compression? Or could it be a feature provided by one of the middleware packages I'm using, such as `helmet` or `morgan`? Any insights or suggestions for further investigation would be greatly appreciated.